# How to search either on id or name for certain purchase orders

Tags: mysql

We would like to filter purchase orders either based on purchase order id (primary key) or name of the purchase order using a single search box.

We used the like parameter to search on the name field, but it doesn't seem to work on the primary key. It works only when we use the equal operator for id(s). But it would be preferable if we can filter purchase orders using like for id(s). How to do this?

```
create table purchase_orders (
id int(11) primary key,
name varchar(255),

...
)
```

Comment: Can you show us sample of data and desired result? Why would you need to use LIKE on ID ?

Comment: I want to see all purchase orders which started in a certain range (maybe 11% implies I want to see all purchase orders in 110 or 111 or 112 or 113 ... till 119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1

```
SELECT *
FROM purchase_orders
WHERE id LIKE '%123%'; -- tribute to TemporaryNickName
```

This is horrible, performance-wise :)

#### Option 2a

Add a text column which receives a string version of `id`. Maybe add some triggers to populate it automatically.

#### Option 2b

Change the type of `id` column to `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` (I believe `CHAR` should be preferred for a primary key).

In both 2a. and 2b. cases, add an index (maybe a `FULLTEXT` one) to this column.

Answer (score 0):

I think LIKE should work. I assume that your SQL wasn't correctly written.
Let's assume that you have order name "ABCDEF" then you can find this using the following query structure.

```
SELECT id FROM purchase_orders WHERE name LIKE '%CD%';
```

To explain it, % sign means it's a wildcard. As a result this query is going to select any String that contains "CD" inside of it.

According to the table structure, varchar can contain 255 characters. I think this is quite a large string and it's probably going to consume a lot of resources and going to take more time to search something using SQL functions like **LIKE**. You can always search it by id

> `WHERE id = something`. This is much faster way btw

, but I don't think order id is an user friendly data, instead I would let users to use product name. My recommendation is to use apache Lucene or MySQL's full text search feature (which can improve search performance).

[Apache lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)

[MySQL Full text search function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

These are tools built to search certain pattern or word through list of large strings in much faster way. Many websites use this to build their own mini search engines. I found mysql full text search function requires pretty much no learning curve and straight forward to use =D